# Can I get the improved appearance of the jQueryUI button while limiting its size?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-button

I like the general look of the jquery ui button, but it is oversized for my purposes. Is there a way to replace the blah look of the generic jQuery button with the pizzazz of the jQueryUI button while restricting its outsizedness?

This jsfiddle shows the diff: http://jsfiddle.net/aSM2r/

(comment out the jQuery to see the generic button).

HTML:

```
<button>Czech this out</button>
```

jQuery:

```
$('button').button();
```

Also, when the button contains an anchor tag, the jQueryUIzed button lacks the underline - not sure if I mind about that, though...

Comment: So clearly, you just want the button to take less space? What did you try to fix the issue by yourself (just so we don't repeat the same steps)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify the css properties to reflect a smaller version of the button, note that I didn't specify anything concrete just reduced the original [`em`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Em_%28typography%29) values for `padding`, `line-height` and `font-size`, to give you a sleeker look.

#### Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thismayhem/nVraZ/)

#### Here's the code:

```
.ui-button-text-only .ui-button-text{
    padding: .2em .5em;
    line-height:1.2;
    font-size:0.8em;
}
```

#### Here's the result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Yes,  just change the CSS for the button to whatever you like.

Comment: I don't want to change the size to a fixed size, though, due to the varying sizes of different devices people use to access web sites.

Comment: @ClayShannon Then use `em` for relative sizing.